# Django query with two foreign-keys

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create an application page. On this page, I show application name. Now, I want to show, if it exists, the DRP application.

urls.py :

```
path('application/<int:application_id>/', views.application, name='application')
```

The models are like that :

```
class Application(models.Model):
    application_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.application_name


class Drp_Application(models.Model):
    application_prod = models.OneToOneField(Application, related_name='drp_application_prod', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application_drp = models.OneToOneField(Application, related_name='drp_application_drp', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.application_prod) + " -> " + str(self.application_drp)
```

`Drp_Application` model contains the link between the production application and the DRP application.

My current working page is like that :

```
def application(request, application_id):
    application = get_object_or_404(Application, pk=application_id)
    # application_drp = ...
    context = {
        'application': application,
        'application_drp': application_drp
    }
    return render(request, 'application.html', context)
```

How should be my request to get the DRP application model from `application_id` in the view of my page `application` ?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT** :

I have found a way to do it, but maybe not as well as possible.

```
application_drp_id = Drp_Application.objects.get(application_prod=application_id)
application_drp = Application.objects.filter(application_name=application_drp_id.application_drp)
```

It's possible in one request ?

Comment: It depends on your `urls.py`.

Comment: What do you mean ? My `urls.py` works with the page `application` : `path('application/<int:application_id>/', views.application, name='application'),`

It's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

When the relation between `Application` and `Drp_Application` is `OneToOne`, then the following way should work:

```
application.drp_application_prod.application_drp
```

### Old Answer

You can simply do it like this(based on [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/))(When its Foreign Key Relation):

In `views.py`(If needed)

```
application.drp_application_prod.all() # to get production apps
application.drp_application_drp.all() # to get drp apps
```

In template:

```
{{ application.drp_application_prod.all }}
{{ application.drp_application_drp.all }}  

// Or just iterate through the list

{% for drp in application.drp_application_prod.all %}
     {{ drp }}
{% endfor %}
```

### Update

```
for drp in application.drp_application_prod.all():
    print(drp.application_drp)

# Or

application.drp_application_prod.values_list('application_drp')  # list queryset
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do it for a special application, with its name. It works, but now, I want to add its DRP application in the same page.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what mean. Can you please update the question with that information? Thanks

Comment: @PhxDev please see my update section of my answer :) hope it helps

Comment: thanks but no ...
`for drp in application.drp_application_prod.all():
AttributeError: 'Drp_Application' object has no attribute 'all'`

`application_drp = application.drp_application_prod.values_list('application_drp')
AttributeError: 'Drp_Application' object has no attribute 'values_list'`

Comment: thats weird. Is the relation between Drp_Application and Application is OneToOne?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to OneToOneField, it's more realistic for my models.

Comment: Then the solution won't work. In that case, you should get value of `application_drp` via `application.drp_application_prod.application_drp`.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks @ruddra, now I understand more how it works ! Thank you for your time and your explanation.

Comment: it's done. Could you update it with your last answer ? I have updated mine with OneToOne :)